# LVM and dm_crypt with MAAS mounting issue

Tags: maas

I'm trying to have MAAS/Curtin encrypt a single drive on deployment and so far I'm hitting some roadblocks when implementing encryption using the dm_crypt module from curtin.

I can have curtin setup the LVM volumes the way I would like but once I add the encryption portion I don't full understand how to mount the encrypted volume(s) after they have been setup. Does that have to be done as an "late command"? I'm not too concerned with having the encryption key in a config file as I handle changing everything after the fact with Ansible.

This is a copy of my existing storage config in /etc/maas/preseed/etc...:

```
storage:
  version: 1
  config:
    - id: sda
      type: disk
      ptable: gpt
      path: /dev/sda
      name: main_disk
      preserve: false
      wipe: superblock-recursive
      grub_device: true
    - id: sda1
      type: partition
      size: 3GB
      device: sda
      flag: boot
    - id: sda5
      type: partition
      size: 50G
      flag: logical
      device: sda
    - id: volgroup1
      name: vg1
      type: lvm_volgroup
      devices:
          - sda5
    - id: lvm_crypt_1
      type: dm_crypt
      dm_name: lvm_crypt
      volume: sda5
      key: testkeytestkeytestkey12345
    - id: sda1_root
      type: format
      fstype: fat32
      volume: sda1
    - id: sda1_mount
      type: mount
      path: /
      device: sda1_root
    - id: lv1_mount
      type: mount
      path: /
      fstype: "ext4"
      device: lvm_crypt_1
```

Answer (score 0):

curtin documentation has a note saying...

Note: Encrypted disks and partitions are tracked in /etc/crypttab and will be mounted at boot time.

See the last section of the Dm-Crypt Command
https://curtin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/storage.html#dm-crypt-command